# previous child of stack widget not active

Tags: flutter, widget

In a stack widget, I have two container children; each with an icon as a child. on view, the child of the first container has a play icon which on pressed should change to a pause icon and the child of the second container has a home icon which on pressed changes to a wallet icon.

the play icon does not change to the pause icon when it is being pressed. and I have noticed it is because the first container has another widget lying on it which is the second container, which is making the content of the first widget inactive.

how do I make it active? Is there any way? there need to be a way.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
runApp(AllTests());
}

class AllTests extends StatefulWidget {
const AllTests({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
_AllTestsState createState() => _AllTestsState();
}

class _AllTestsState extends State<AllTests> {
IconData home = Icons.home;
IconData play = Icons.play_circle_filled;
onHomePress() {
if (home == Icons.home) {
  home = Icons.account_balance_wallet_rounded;
} else {
  home = Icons.home;
}
}
onPlayPress() {
if (play == Icons.play_circle_filled) {
  play = Icons.pause_circle_filled_rounded;
} else {
  play = Icons.play_circle_filled;
}
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Stack(
          overflow: Overflow.visible,
            children: [
          Positioned(
            top: 50,
            child: Container(
              height: 300,
              width: 500,
              color: Colors.pink,
              child:  IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  play,
                  size: 80,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    print('hello');
                    onPlayPress();
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(

            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0),
              child: Container(
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
                color: Colors.yellow,
                child:  IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    home,
                    size: 80,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      onHomePress();
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ]),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

[image: this is how it looks now]

Comment: Why do you need the the first container so much larger than the icon, and then the other icon stacked on top of it? Maybe post a screenshot...I'm having a hard time figuring out how this arrangement would look. There might be a better way to build the UI without the overlap, like could you put the icons in a Row() or Column() inside your Stack() so they don't overlap?  You can wrap widgets with an IgnorePointer() but I don't think that'll work for what you're trying to do.

Comment: the UI that I am building requires a stack, one widget on top of the other. and This is not what exactly what I am doing, this is just a small part of a bigger project, so to answer why the first container should be so much larger........ this is just a scenario.

Comment: and I will add a screenshot soon @Pat9RB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `overflow: Overflow.visible` which is causing the play button to be visible even if it is outside of the `Stack`. Checkout following code which resolves that issue.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(AllTests());
}

class AllTests extends StatefulWidget {
  const AllTests({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AllTestsState createState() => _AllTestsState();
}

class _AllTestsState extends State<AllTests> {
  IconData home = Icons.home;
  IconData play = Icons.play_circle_filled;
  onHomePress() {
    if (home == Icons.home) {
      home = Icons.account_balance_wallet_rounded;
    } else {
      home = Icons.home;
    }
  }

  onPlayPress() {
    if (play == Icons.play_circle_filled) {
      play = Icons.pause_circle_filled_rounded;
    } else {
      play = Icons.play_circle_filled;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            const Spacer(),
            Expanded(
              child: Stack(
//           overflow: Overflow.visible,
                children: [
                  Positioned(
                    top: 50,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 300,
                      width: 500,
                      color: Colors.pink,
                      child: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          play,
                          size: 80,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            print('hello');
                            onPlayPress();
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 100,
                        width: 100,
                        color: Colors.yellow,
                        child: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            home,
                            size: 80,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              onHomePress();
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also you can take a look at [AnimatedIcon](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AnimatedIcon-class.html) to use animated [play_pause](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AnimatedIcons/play_pause-constant.html) button.

Comment: your code works alright, the icon changes when pressed. but what was the main cause? If it was the overflow property, I uncommented it to see what would happen, but the code was still working, I mean the icon changes when is pressed. now I went ahead and tried it in my own code, once I commented the overflow property out, parts of the containers disappeared even including the icon.

Comment: was the icon inactive when you run the my code on your IDE and Emulator before applying your changes?

Comment: Yes the play Icon was inactive on overflown part when I tested your code, the problem there was the `Column` widget was only occupying the the dimensions you allotted to the last child or home button and not the whole screen and because you added `Overflow.visible` even though the play button container was going out of bounds it was visible but not clickable (if you run your code and try to tap on some part of play button which is within the bounds you will find that it is clickable). Because of this I made the `Column` widget occupy the whole screen.

Comment: And added the two buttons in `Expanded` widget which will allow the `Stack` to occupy as much space as it needs added `Spacer` widget to occupy remaining space on top. Because i put the `Stack` in `Expanded` widget the `Stack` will not overflow therefore adding or removing `overflow: Overflow.visible` will not make any difference.

Comment: you are awesome :) Thanks, it worked

Answer (score 1):

While using `Stack` provide its size. In column, you can wrap with SizedBox. And On Widget tree, UI priority is bottom to top, when you have small tappable widget over large one, place at last on stack children.

Here is your widget.

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(AllTests());
}

class AllTests extends StatefulWidget {
  const AllTests({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AllTestsState createState() => _AllTestsState();
}

class _AllTestsState extends State<AllTests> {
  IconData home = Icons.home;
  IconData play = Icons.play_circle_filled;
  onHomePress() {
    if (home == Icons.home) {
      home = Icons.account_balance_wallet_rounded;
    } else {
      home = Icons.home;
    }
  }

  onPlayPress() {
    if (play == Icons.play_circle_filled) {
      play = Icons.pause_circle_filled_rounded;
    } else {
      play = Icons.play_circle_filled;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 100 + 300 + 40,

              /// total height F
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Positioned(
                    top: 50,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 300,
                      width: 500,
                      color: Colors.pink,
                      child: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          play,
                          size: 80,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            print('hello');
                            onPlayPress();
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 0,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 100,
                        width: 100,
                        color: Colors.yellow,
                        child: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            home,
                            size: 80,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              onHomePress();
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks but, I don't need you to change the arrangement. I want it to work with this arrangement.

Comment: Can you test my widget and does it have the same output as you?

Comment: I have run your code, but i noticed you changed the position of the widgets

Comment: Position on UI or position on widget tree?

Comment: sorry about that, i think i run a different code. your code is working, but mine still is not, so I want to know what exactly you changed or added. the sizedbox alone?